# Popup window in Java when a USB port scans some input

Tags: java, swing, port, qr-code, port-scanning

I have an application written on Java running on the machine (Linux/Windows). I want to make this application run like a background application so that it does not interrupt while using other applications in the system. Now I want to popup a screen and show some buttons (to do some tasks based on the selection) when a QR Code is scanned using a scanned attached to the USB port. When this scanning happens my Java application that initiates the popup screen is running in the system tray.

--Edit--
I have used key listeners to identify the bar code scanning and pull out information from database based on what is scanned. But while scanning my application, was open. So I attached the action listeners in the AWT level so that the key strokes/scanning is caught and taken care off. But now in the current case I wont be having any windows active. SO I NEED TO CAPTURE THE SCANNED INPUT INTERNALLY WHEN THE APPLICATION IS MINIMIZED IN THE SYSTEM TRAY.

Comment: No i dunno how to start with.. Probably if you guys give some tips to start with i can take off.. Check my edit..

Comment: Does your scanner just look like a USB-HID keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only avenue open to you is capturing system-wide keyboard events. There is a library that handles that for Java: [jnativehook](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/). But how you're going to detect which events are coming specifically from your HID device, I'm not sure.

There is also the  [JavaHIDAPI](http://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/), an amateur-level project whose "hello, world" test example failed with IOException on my machine. The good part is, all the code is there, including the native C for Windows.

Finally, I found [this](http://www.blog.kslemb.com/doku.php/en/projects/globx/java_hid), a very good tutorial on how to talk to HID's on Windows.

Comment: can i do this by some kind of port monitoring ?? so tat i will set my application to monitor a particular USB port and runs from the system tray. When there is some data scanned on the scanner attached to the particular USB port activate the application from system tray and show the application screen!!

Comment: I tried using the library you have suggested but its capturing all key events.. Which is not what i want. I want to capture the key events coming from specific USB port not every thing.

Comment: Yes, exactly as I feared. I guess there is no "advanced" part af that API that checks the source?

Comment: is there any other way of achieving this though ??

Comment: You can check out the project [JavaHIDAPI](http://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/). It's an amateur-level project, though, and their sample code failed on my machine. However, all the sources are there, including the native lib sources, so if you know what you're doing, it could be a start.

Comment: I also found [this](http://www.blog.kslemb.com/doku.php/en/projects/globx/java_hid), it could be useful. It explains how to communicate with HIDS through JNA. Still, you'll have to get your hands dirty.

Answer (score 2):

You can see if [*Headless Mode*](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/) works or start up [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) on your host.

Comment: why VNC ?? im not remotely controlling anything. I just want to talk to database when a QR code is scanned. But while scanning the java application will be in system tray!!

Comment: The way I understand it, headless mode (or VNC on older JVMs) would work when no one is on the console. It looks like you want this to work for the current user, so it won't help. Sorry.